# Automapper - Using custom type converters with dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I've just turned to using AutoMapper via dependency injections opposed to manual configuration. My profiles are all coming through fine now, but my custom type converters are not.

I was under the impression that using services.AddAutoMapper() along with implementations of ITypeConverter<,> would do the trick, as below in Startup.cs. I can see the Types are added in as Transient to the services but I haven't tracked down how this is meant to translate into creating a map.

```
        public class DateTimeToDateConverter : ITypeConverter<DateTime, Date>
        {
            public Date Convert(DateTime source, Date destination, ResolutionContext context)
            {
                return Date.FromDateTime(source);
            }
        }
    
        public class DateToDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<Date, DateTime>
        {
            public DateTime Convert(Date source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
            {
                return source.ToDateTime();
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup)));
```

My original code for manual configuration is below. I assume there must be something obvious that I'm missing as to how to get the dependency injection doing the same thing!

```
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, Date>().ConvertUsing(s => Date.FromDateTime(s));
                cfg.CreateMap<Date, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(s => s.ToDateTime());
                cfg.AddMaps(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMappingConfiguration)));
            });
```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I'm afraid that link is taking me to a 'page doesn't exist'.

Is the content different to the two links below?

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: No. There are a few simple steps and a link to a working example. There are also passing tests in the DI repo.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and for pointing me in the direction of downloading the repos - I'm new to GitHub so not something I'm used to.

I haven't found a useful example project but off the back of your advice I've cloned the Automapper DI extension project.
So far, I am concluding that another Profile is required to manage the converters, at which point the converters themselves become irrelevant to some extent. I just had to write the two lines in my second screenshot again.

Am I still missing something? I'm questioning what's the point in the ITypeConverter?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/search?q=convertusing

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's what I'm saying - I have to create a profile that manages all of the ITypeConverters with a .ConvertUsing.

I feel this is unintuitive within the DI concept that suggests it's all managed for you. It means there's no point in me defining an ITypeConverter<> because I have to write a convert using anyway.

I expected reflection within the AddAutoMapper() method to be managing that for me. I can write a profile and an extension for that though.

I feel like I'm not the only one who will encounter this the first time they try to use so hopefully the post can add value.

Comment: No. Of course you have to make the connection between the map and the converter, but where you define the converters, that's your business. I can see you're missing smth, but I'm not sure what :)